# How to create a custom api for mobile app in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, api, custom, customapi

I want to create custom APIs for a mobile app tp cop up with my Magento 2.3 .x project.

Like APIs for plugins installed like cc avenue, store locator plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased any premium module you can approach vendor to provide rest API for the module. it would be great if vendor provide Rest API for their module.

Or else

you can create your custom rest API by below guide.

you can see and follow below guide to getting started with first API.

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-api/

Hope this solution will helpful for you.

Thank you.

Comment: I have already go through with this link.Any how thanks